# Heroku: Push rejected, Failed to compile PHP app

Tags: php, magento, github

Trying to deploy my magento app I have this error occured: but working in localhost

[image]

I really don't understand why, and I am not sure it is in relation with php buildpack. Before this error not appear and I have the same configuration as before.

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
}
```

Help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php --region eu
```

reference

https://chrisgrice.com/magento-on-heroku-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

make sure auth.json in placed inside magento root directory and also make sure auth.json key are placed correctly .

Comment: Thank you placed in Root directory . After Changing Error Cleared.